# Cannot rebuild sitecore indexes with coveo

Tags: search, indexing, sitecore, search-engine, sitecore7

I have configured Coveo with my sitecore instance as stated [here](https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SC201412/Coveo+for+Sitecore+Installation+and+Upgrade+Guide) but unfortunately I am not able to [rebuild indexes](https://developers.coveo.com/display/SC201412/Rebuilding+Your+Search+Indexes). Below is the image of the error that I am getting on trying to rebuild with **Indexing Manager** (Sitecore Start Menu > Control Panel > Indexing > Indexing Manager)

[image]

Comment: What version Coveo for Sitecore are you using? Free or enterprise?

Comment: I am using the free version of Coveo for sitecore

Comment: Then make sure you are using latest version of the free version, i think it's December version, and also make sure you removed all lucene specific config files

Comment: yes!! I moved the right assemblies with the required version but now I am stuck with this error: 

Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Sitecore.ContentSearch.IProviderCrawler> Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.get_Crawlers()'.

Comment: What do you mean by "you moved the right assemblies"? how did you install the package? pretty sure something went wrong when installing the package, try re-installing it again

Comment: as per this guy [here](https://answers.coveo.com/questions/1565/coveo-for-sitecore-not-working-on-a-new-instance?page=1&focusedAnswerId=1712#1712), he ran into a similar situation and suggested to install the latest version for coveo where as I am already using the latest coveo version that is 'Coveo for Sitecore 70 3.0 (863)' for required sitecore version that is 7.0

Comment: Right assemblies as in, sitecore.contentsearch.dll was supposed to be of version 1.0.0.0 so I had to do the requisite replacement.

I am new to CMS plus coding so it is a bit tricky for me to understand the issues that fast.

Comment: Then try to contact Coveo support for help, its hard to figure what's wrong in your installation here

Comment: yes I have done that. Thank you any ways!! It was a pleasure discussing with you